# I want to tokenizise the sql table and here is my table and my required output

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp

table name : postdet

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════════════════╗
║ user     ║        post                  ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║ pons     ║ near our temple an car crush ║
║ subbu    ║ oh ok                        ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════════════════╝
```

this is my table having user and post as column names

No i want this output.
The data in the post should be split by space and include '<''>' symbols

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ user     ║              post                        ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ pons     ║ <near> <our> <temple> <an> <car> <crush> ║
║ subbu    ║ <oh> <ok>                                ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

pls help me with codes

Comment: select 
user,
concat('<',replace(trim(post),' ','> <'),'>') as post 
from postdet

Comment: Do you want to `Mon Oct 05 14:30:27 IST 2015` into **`<Mon Oct 05 14:30:27 IST 2015>`** or **`<Mon> <Oct> <05> <14:30:27> <IST> <2015>`**?

Comment: I want the output in which the column should split and have tag in each word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be `replace` and `concat` something as

```
mysql> select concat('<',replace(trim('near our temple an car crush'),' ','> <'),'>') as s ;
+------------------------------------------+
| s                                        |
+------------------------------------------+
| <near> <our> <temple> <an> <car> <crush> |
+------------------------------------------+
```

So the query becomes if you want to do at the time of select as

```
select 
user,
concat('<',replace(trim(post),' ','> <'),'>') as post 
from postdet
```

Comment: I try above query and the result ,I  got was 
Tokenizise Form
pons : <  > Mon Oct 05 14:30:27 IST 2015 
subbu : <  > Mon Oct 05 14:30:27 IST 2015

Comment: The above query was with respect to the sample data you provided. If you have some other data format please specify them into the question and expected result.

Comment: Actually, I have the mentioned table which is the thing I have Sir. I want to split the data inside the column post and tag them as I already mentioned .  the date and time are just display fancy .it is not recorded in the database table .the original table is the one I mentioned

Comment: So is the above query working for you ? if not what is not working explain them into the question.

Comment: post column is not displaying in the query

Comment: if the result is to be displayed on a webpage try this query instead _select user, concat('&lt;',replace(trim(post),' ','&gt; &lt;'),'&gt;') as post FROM postdet;_

Comment: Thanks PaulF. Its amazing. Its works I get the required output..Thanks for all friends .........

Comment: PaulF your answer is what I was looking for.You are a genius.Thanks.